# Why does Xorg come up in 1024x768 mode instead of full 1600x1200 resolution?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, freebsd, xrandr, xorg.conf

I have Xorg configured to use the radeon-driver and run two monitors I have attached to my Radeon HD 5670 card. It works.

But, every time Xorg restarts, it comes up in 1024x768-mode with monitors *mirroring* each other. I then have to use `xrandr` (or KDE's GUI for same) to manually set the 1600x1200 mode (which is the native resolution for my monitors) and to complement each other instead of mirroring.

How can I convince the Xorg-server to come up in that mode automatically? The `"ServerLayout"` section of my `xorg.conf` reads:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        Option  "XINERAMA"
EndSection
```

The `"Device"`:

```
Section "Device"
        Option     "DRI"        "2"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "radeon"
        VendorName  "Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI"
        BoardName   "Redwood [Radeon HD 5670]"
        BusID       "PCI:7:0:0"
EndSection
```

And the `"Screen"`:

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
...
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
                Modes   "1600x1200"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Sorry for being late replying, but did you ever fix your problem?   I could try to help you troubleshoot if not.   Did you manually make your xorg.conf ?

Comment: Well, I copied the Files-section listing the fonts-directories into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/files.conf` and removed the rest. Whatever was wrong with the settings before, no Xorg comes up as I want it to -- using the defaults for everything except fonts. Don't know, why Radeon needed me to do this. When I tried the same config with an NVidia card, it also worked as expected.

Comment: What drivers are you using? Have you tried using aticonfig to setup your Xorg?

Comment: Well, the `radeon` driver -- the xf86-video-ati from [here](https://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/driver/). Never heard of `aticonfig`...

Comment: I should have noticed the driver.. sorry. Option "ZaphodHeads" "string"

Specify the RandR output(s) to use with zaphod mode for a particular driver instance. If you use this option you must use this option for all instances of the driver. 
For example: Option "ZaphodHeads" "LVDS,VGA-0" will assign xrandr outputs LVDS and VGA-0 to this instance of the driver.    Source: https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/radeon.4.xhtml also check out: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#Multihead_setup